# table cell content

Tags: javascript

my goal is to make a javascript that i will run using my browser (on someone elses site, not mine) that will take a number from thar site and wait some time depending on the number on the site before clicking a button.

the number is kind of hard to find: in this site there is a table in this table there is a table cell, i got the ID from the cell (for now lets call it "tCell") inside this cell there is another table this does not have an ID, in this table there is a row (once again no ID) in this row there is two cells, and the number is the only content of this cell.

now how do i go from that cell i have an ID on to the content i want?
(how to find the content of a cell then go to the right row of the table among this content)

i guess i will have to use something like this:

```
var something = document.getElementById('tCell');
```

and then what...

Comment: So, could you show the HTML source / link to this site?

Comment: If you have jQuery, its fairly simple. If you have, I can hint code.

Comment: The shortest way to get the contents of the first cell of the table's first row in something: `something.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[0].cells[0].textContent`. Because this element is also the first cell inside something, this is sufficient: `something.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].textContent`. If you have to support IE, add a condition test to check whether you have to use `innerText` or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
var something = document.getElementById('tCell');
var table = something.firstChild;
var tbody = table.firstChild;
var row = tbody.firstChild;
var firstTd = row.firstChild;
var secondTd = firstTd.nextSibling;    
var textNode = secondTd.firstChild;
var textNodeValue = textNode.nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('tCell').getElementsByTagName("table")[0].getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[1].innerHTML`

Will provide you with the number, in string format.

Comment: `innerHTML` doesn't only show the text, but also any HTML, if existent.

Comment: There is no other content of that box - it says so in the question.